# local variable issue in c++

Tags: c++, local-variables

I just started learning the very basics of c++, I have experience with vb.net and c#

Now I thought to get the basics covered some Project euler problems would be a good excercise. I ran into a very strange problem by trying to solve [Problem 4](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4), probably because of a lack of understanding of c++ yet.

I got 2 scenario's, one is working, one is not(> the a variable just jumps from 999 to 768 when the sprintf command is executed as shown below), now my question is: Why is this happening in solution 1? The only difference is the loop variables a and b are declared before the loop as in solution 2 they are declared with the loop.

Solution 1 (not working):

```
int a =999;
int b =999;
int lb = 100;
int c = 0;
char strNumber[6];
int result = 0;
int ra = 0;
int rb = 0;
for (a=999; a>=100; a--){
    for (b = a; b>=lb; b--){
        c = a * b;
        sprintf(strNumber, "%d", c);
        if (isPalindrome(strNumber)){
            if (c > result){
                result = c;
                lb = b;
                rb = b;
                ra = a;
            }
            b = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Solution 2 (working):

```
int lb = 100;
int c = 0;
char strNumber[6];
int result = 0;
int ra = 0;
int rb = 0;

for (int a=999; a>=100; a--){
    for (int b = a; b>=lb; b--){
        c = a * b;
        sprintf(strNumber, "%d", c);
        if (isPalindrome(strNumber)){
            if (c > result){
                result = c;
                lb = b;
                rb = b;
                ra = a;
            }
            b = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to leave room for the null terminator byte, so your `char` array needs to contain at least 7 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first time through the loop, `c` is going to be a 6-digit number (999²).
The `sprintf(strNumber, "%d", c);` will thus write **7** chars to `strNumber`: the six digits and the famous null terminator. Since you only reserved six chars for `strNumber`, that last write will clobber something.

It happens not to appear to clobber something important in your second case, but that's just "luck", your code's behavior is undefined in both cases.

Reserve an extra char in `strNumber` and both versions should work the same as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4):

Actually both has same problem, namely **undefined behavior**. The problem stems from here:

```
char strNumber[6];
```

This variable *cannot* accomodate the value of `999 x 999` in string representation, bevause there is also a null character `'\0'` at the end. So when you call `sprintf` to convert the integer into its string representation, right there inside the function it invokes undefined behaviour when it tries to put the character`'\0'` at index `6`, because the indices `0` to `5` are already occupied by six digits of `998001` which is the product of `999 x 999`.

You should define it at least of size `7`:

```
char strNumber[7]; //one char for null-character.
```

As for why your second code is working is because you're being lucky (rather *unlucky*). That is what undefined behavior means: **anything could happen**. It may run, or may not. Neither the language specification nor the compiler gives any guarantee of the behavior, hence *undefined* behavior.

As @James Kanze pointed out in the comment that the real solution is to forget about `sprintf`, and better use `std::ostringstream` and `std::string` as:

```
#include <sstream> //for std::ostringstream 
#include <string>  //for std::string 

std::ostringstream ss;
ss << number;
std::string s = ss.str(); //get the string representation of the number
```

Comment: The real solution here (and elsewhere) is to forget about `sprintf`, and use `std::ostringstream`.  Why go looking for trouble?

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I hadn't come to learn about ostringstream yet, I will look into that next. Just beginning to learn and expecting a book in the mail next week.